# R: sample from independent random generators

Tags: r, random

I have an R code like this.

```
D1 <- runif(0,1); 
D2 <- runif(0,1); 
U1 <- runif(0,1); 
U2 <- runif(0,1);
```

but I don't want Ds and Us to consume the same distribution!!

How can I do something behaving like this?

```
distrD <- rand(seed1) 
distrU <- rand(seed2) 

D1 <- distrD.runif(0,1); 
D2 <- distrD.runif(0,1); 
U1 <- distrU.runif(0,1); 
U2 <- distrU.runif(0,1); 

distr_D <- rand(seed1) 
distr_U <- rand(seed2) 

nD1 <- distr_D.runif(0,1); 
nU1 <- distr_U.runif(0,1); 
nU2 <- distr_U.runif(0,1); 
nD2 <- distr_D.runif(0,1);
```

giving random numbers fulfilling this:

```
nD1 == D1 
nD2 == D2 
nU1 == U1 
nU2 == U2
```

I don't know in advance how many times each distribution is 
asked for a new number. So I cannot store it in an array.

Suggestions?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. If you want different distributions, you need to pass different parameters to `runif`. The seed is not something you need to consider there. Also, you should explain what you want to achieve with this. That nested `while` loop is deadly for performance.

Comment: Also `runif(0,1)` will return a zero-length vector..

Comment: From a performance stand point I would generate a large amount of random numbers and draw from that. Just make sure to generate enough numbers that it covers all possibilities. If this is not possible due to memory usage, I would simply generate a 100000 random numbers and check if they have all been used within the loop. If so, generate new numbers. But that is more in general, I agree with @Roland that your question is rather vague right now.

Comment: @Roland I'm considering withdrawing my qyestion because it seems so confused. 
I want the same distribution (flat) for both Ds and Us, but I want the Ds to always be the same sequence independently of the number of times I sampled the Us between one D and the other.

Comment: If you implement @PaulHiemstra's advice that should be easy. Generate two sets of randoms that are large enough and get your values from those. And don't withdraw your question. Improve it.

Comment: I think you are looking for the `set.seed` function, but still not clear how exactly you want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
library(rngtools)

Dseeds <- RNGseq(2, seed = 1)
Useeds <- RNGseq(2, seed = 2)

RNGseed(Dseeds[[1]])
D1 <- runif(1, 0, 1)
RNGseed(Dseeds[[2]])
D2 <- runif(1, 0, 1)
RNGseed(Useeds[[1]])
U1 <- runif(1, 0, 1) 
RNGseed(Useeds[[2]])
U2 <- runif(1, 0, 1) 

RNGseed(Dseeds[[1]])
nD1 <- runif(1, 0, 1)
RNGseed(Useeds[[1]])
nU1 <- runif(1, 0, 1)
RNGseed(Useeds[[2]])
nU2 <- runif(1, 0, 1)
RNGseed(Dseeds[[2]])
nD2 <- runif(1, 0, 1)

nD1 == D1 
#[1] TRUE
nD2 == D2 
#[1] TRUE
nU1 == U1 
#[1] TRUE
nU2 == U2 
#[1] TRUE
```

Draw as many seeds as you think you might need (an overestimate should be possible). If you need more you can use something like `RNGseq(n, Dseeds[[2]])[-1]`.

Of course, it would be better to draw two samples of random numbers (setting the seed each time) and store the seed after producing each of them in order to reset the seed to that value when you'd need to produce additional randoms for one of the samples.